# Tridiagonal matrix algorithm /Thomas algorithm issues

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am pretty new to programming and struggling with my Java code for the tridiagonal matrix algorithm.

The tridagonal matrix is formed as a double array, length 3 at the 1st level, lengths n-1,n and n-1 respectively at the 2nd level

The code compiles but is not producing the right vector. Was wondering if someone can spot the error. Also there is a divisibility by 0 issue in the formula, is there some way to get around this? I have seen this algorithm in other languages but am not experienced enough to see the error! Thanks for your help

```
static double [] linearSolve( double [][] T, double [] v)
{
    double []x ;
    x= new double [v.length];

    if (T== null || v == null)
    { 
        x = null;
    }
    else if (isValidTridiagonal(T)== true && v.length==T[1].length) 
    { 

        T[0][0]=T[0][0]/T[1][0];
        v[0]= v[0]/T[1][0];
        x = new double [v.length];

        for (int j=1;j<v.length-1;j++)
        {


            double d = 1.0/(T[1][j]-(T[0][j-1]*T[2][j]));
            T[0][j]= T[0][j]*d;
            v[j]= v[j]-(T[2][j]*v[j-1]*d);
        }

        x[v.length-1]=v[v.length-1];
        for(int j=v.length-2;j!=-1;j--)
        {
            x[j]=v[j]-T[0][j]*x[j+1];
        }
        return x;

    }
    else
    {
        x =null;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Hi thanks,  yeah I was still having issues after looking through the debugger :(

Comment: But has the debugger helped you to narrow down the issue to something we can help with?

Comment: Honestly I can't work out the issue which is why I'm posting, it's a last resort

Comment: You cannot dump 39 lines of code onto Stack Overflow and say "This isn't working, please fix it."  We won't.  When you get out into the real world, you will certainly have to debug software containing many thousands of lines.  A simple 39-line program like should be easy to debug, and you should use this as a practice opportunity.

Comment: Now, if you can narrow it down to no more than 5 lines, we will reconsider.